# how to change column into row from grouping sql big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, aggregate

i have a table SQL similar like this picture:
[image: existing table]

i want to change the table into something like this, based on their group type.

[image]

I'm still have an issue how to change the table, to adding type "attribution / immediate" can somebody suggest me how to do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Simple variant, to "pivot/unpivot" by auxiliary cte or subquery, applicable if a fixed set of additional columns is specified

```
with types as( select 'attribution' typeX union all select 'immidate'
)
select device,typeX
 ,case when b.typeX='attribution' then session_attribution
       when b.typeX='immidate' then session_immidate
  else null
  end  session
 ,case when b.typeX='attribution' then order_attribution
       when b.typeX='immidate' then order_immidate
  else null
  end  orderX
from tableA a join types b on 1=1
order by typeX,device
```

JOIN on condition like 1=1 my be replaced by CROSS APPLY.

Using names similar to reserved words - practice leading to syntactic and semantic errors. In example changer type->typeX, order->orderX.